# Error installing Jetstream Livewire Basic Authentication on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-7, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to do a fresh install of Laravel 8 with Livewire basic authentication. Basic Laravel installs fine but when installing Jetstream and running "npm install && npm run dev", I get the error.

I found this link where it indicates that there is a problem with laravel mix:

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/installation

where says:

---

**You won't find a webpack.config.js file in your project root. By default, Laravel defers to the config file from this repo. However, should you need to configure it, you may copy the file to your project root, and then update your package.json NPM scripts accordingly: cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js ./.**

---

**but I don't understand exactly what I have to do.**

update your package.json with what ??

Copy the webpack.config.js file to the project's root folder, rerun npm install and npm run dev and the problem persists.

The server is Centos7. I will appreciate help with the problem as I am absolutely stuck with this issue.
I'm about to go to Taylor's house to ask for an explanation! Thanks!

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/home/myproyect/public_html/proyect/proyectlar/node_modules/cross-env/src/index.js:23
    )
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myproyect/public_html/proyect/proyectlar/node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js:3:18)

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/myproyect/public_html/proyect/proyectlar/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/myproyect/public_html/proyect/proyectlar/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update you npm and nodejs.

I had the same problem, and after update them, it works.

npm - 6.14.8
node - 14.15.1